# Get actual opened db connection

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

How can I check if a db-connection is open in PHP?

How can I get a reference to this connection?

How can I determine if it is MySQL, Postgres or something else?

Comment: I open my DB with mysql_connect() and pg_connect(), I use no special library.

Comment: do you know the variable name of the (potentially) open connection ?

Comment: no I don't know the variable name.

Comment: What is the context of your problem?  Where is the DB connection getting opened that you can't access the variable it is assigned to?

Comment: I have different SQL-Statement for supporting different databases. At this time MySQL and PostgreSQL. The connection is opened somewhere else. I will have to check if I could get variable of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you would know the variable the connection is saved into. Without this it becomes a hassle to find it. It means you would have to loop through every variable and test each one, but doing this for any reason can be a pain because it wont find variables outside of the current scope. You can loop the current variables using:

```
foreach(get_defined_vars() as $x){
    // Code
}
```

To check if a variable is a valid connection you can use the below code, it should return an integer:

```
if(mysql_thread_id($connection){
    // Connection exists
}
```

Once you know its a connection you can use the following to return the type of connection, eg, mysql.

```
echo get_resource_type($connection);
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to iterate over every defined variable and figure out if it's a resource handle or not. Try [get_defined_vars()](http://php.net/get_defined_vars).

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best solution to the problem is to not lose track of the DB connection in the first place.

Consider integrating an ORM into your project such as [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org/), or if you want something a little more lightweight, consider a DBAL such as [Zend_Db](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html).  All of these solutions encapsulate the database connections in class instances, ensuring that they are always available to your code if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In general terms, I don't think it's really possible, not at least with some sort of complicate workaround. You can, for instance, loop through all defined variables:

```
foreach(get_defined_vars() as $variable){
    if( is_resource($variable) && get_resource_type($variable)=='mysql link' ){
            // Found a connection!
        var_dump($variable);
    }
}
```

Though, in fact, a connection remains available even if assigned to a local variable out of current scope:

```
function foo(){
    $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'test', 'test');
}
foo();
$res = mysql_query('SELECT NOW() AS what_is_the_time');
if( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) ){
    var_dump($row);
}
```

The problem is that PHP doesn't really care about variables when talking about connections:

```
// One connection and zero variables!
mysql_connect('localhost', 'test', 'test');
$res = mysql_query('SELECT NOW() AS what_is_the_time');
if( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) ){
    var_dump($row);
}
```

You can try and find information about current connection:

```
var_dump(mysql_thread_id());
// int(2696)
```

... though many of the functions will just attempt to stablish a new connection if there isn't one so must take care of warnings...:

> Warning: mysql_thread_id(): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>   bool(false)

... unless [your configuration](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php#ini.mysql.default-password) actually allows a succesful credential-less connnection attempt.

*I'm pretty sure that, whatever you want to do, can be done in an entirely different way :)*